# How to embed a Gist using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, gist

I'm trying to embed a Gist using ReactJS, but I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

Here's my component:

```
var EmbeddedGist = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div id="gist-container" />
        );
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        var src = this.props.srcUrl + ".js";
        $('#gist-container').html('<script src="' + src + '"></script>');
    }
});
```

I'm calling it from within another component, as such:

```
<EmbeddedGist srcUrl="https://gist.github.com/awalGarg/a5bd02978cecf3703f61" />
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Gist embed script uses `document.write` to write the HTML that makes up the embedded Gist into the document's HTML. However, by the time your React component adds the `script` tag, it's too late to write to the document.

While you can't add the Gist embed script to your page dynamically, you *can* get the *contents* of the Gist via JSONP and write that into the document yourself. Here's a component that takes a `gist` property and an optional `file` property and renders the gist for you.

```javascript
var EmbeddedGist = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    gist: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired, // e.g. "username/id"
    file: React.PropTypes.string // to embed a single specific file from the gist
  },

  statics: {
    // Each time we request a Gist, we'll need to generate a new
    // global function name to serve as the JSONP callback.
    gistCallbackId: 0,
    nextGistCallback: function() {
      return "embed_gist_callback_" + EmbeddedGist.gistCallbackId++;
    },

    // The Gist JSON data includes a stylesheet to add to the page
    // to make it look correct. `addStylesheet` ensures we only add
    // the stylesheet one time.
    stylesheetAdded: false,
    addStylesheet: function(href) {
      if (!EmbeddedGist.stylesheetAdded) {
        EmbeddedGist.stylesheetAdded = true;
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.type = "text/css";
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.href = href;

        document.head.appendChild(link);
      }
    }
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      src: ""
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    // Create a JSONP callback that will set our state
    // with the data that comes back from the Gist site
    var gistCallback = EmbeddedGist.nextGistCallback();
    window[gistCallback] = function(gist) {
      if (this.isMounted()) {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          src: gist.div
        });
        EmbeddedGist.addStylesheet(gist.stylesheet);
      }
    }.bind(this);

    var url = "https://gist.github.com/" + this.props.gist + ".json?callback=" + gistCallback;
    if (this.props.file) {
      url += "&file=" + this.props.file;
    }

    // Add the JSONP script tag to the document.
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  },

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <div>loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.src}} />;
    }
  }
});
```

You can use it like this:

```javascript
var app = (
  <div>
    <EmbeddedGist gist="BinaryMuse/a57ae1a551472e06b29a" file="restful.js" />
    <hr />
    <EmbeddedGist gist="BinaryMuse/bb9f2cbf692e6cfa4841" />
  </div>
);

React.render(app, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Take a look at [this example of it working on JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/nrb6zxfw/): http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/nrb6zxfw/

One way to improve this would to ensure that an existing `EmbeddedGist` component that has its `gist` or `file` prop change would update to use the new data by hooking into `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: I made a es6 version: https://gist.github.com/aVolpe/b364a8fcd10f1ba833d97e9ab278f42c

Answer (score 2):

I implemented it with updating of the props using componentWillRecieveProps like binaryMuse suggested.

Did something like this:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    this._getGistData(this.props.gist,this.props.file);
},

componentWillReceiveProps: function (nextProps) {
    if (this.props.gist !== nextProps.gist || this.props.file !== nextProps.file) {
        this._getGistData(nextProps.gist,nextProps.file);
    }
},
```

Where _getGistData is simply the original code that was in componentDidMount

Comment: this is a lot smaller and simpler than the marked answer, is it as good?

Comment: who is B mouse?

Comment: @SuperUberDupe its in the suggested answer. At the end of the answer he suggested "One way to improve this would to ensure that an existing EmbeddedGist component that has its gist or file prop change would update to use the new data by hooking into componentWillReceiveProps."